# One question on two stacks

Tags: feature-request, support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it necessary to be able to cross-post between sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/is-it-necessary-to-be-able-to-cross-post-between-sites)

Is it possible to ask a question on Stack Overflow as well as on GameDev? A lot of these programming questions sometimes seem to be relevant for both sites, but I don't want to post them twice.

Is it in some way possible to add a question to both stacks or should I actually copy the question? Or is this a feature request on the complete stackExchange?

Comment: I actually make a point of asking such questions in slightly different ways, tailored to the related forums. (i.e. GameDev will likely garner answers with a different point of view from Overflow, which can be valuable.)  Many of the topics discussed on Stack are quite nuanced.